# Not recognising hyphen on split

Tags: python, text, split, nlp

I'm working with about 24k text files and am splitting some lines on '-'. It works for some files, however it fails to split for some other files.

`company_participants` is a list with `N >= 1` elements, with each element consisting of a name followed by a hyphen ("-"), followed by the job title. To get the names, I use:

```
names_participants = [name.split('-')[0].strip() for name in company_participants]
```

On closer inspection, I found that it does not recognise "-" as "-" for some reason.

For example, the first element in `company_participants` is "robert isom - president"

Calling `company_participants[0].split()[2]` returns "-" since I've split on whitespace, and the hyphen is the third element (index 2).

When I then run a boolean on whether this is equal to "-", I get False.

```
company_participants[0].split()[2] == "-"  # Item at index 2 is the hyphen
# Output = False
```

Any idea what's going on here? Is there something else that looks like a hyphen but isn't one?

Many thanks!

Comment: Could by `binary encoded strings`: `b'-' != '-'`

Comment: `company_participants[0].split()[2] == b"-"` still returns False unfortunately. I also double checked the type (`type(company_participants[0].split()[2])`) and that returns `str`

Comment: I would suggest you to check type of `company_participants_full[0].split()[2]`.

Comment: Checked and that's a str. But I seem to have found the solution; posting now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found that this has actually been answered elsewhere on StackOverflow.

Apparently I'm dealing with a "dash" and not a "hyphen"; couldn't see the difference with me naked eyes but when I copied the symbol from [here](https://unicode-table.com/en/2013/), then it recognised it such that `company_participants[0].split()[2] == "–"` returned True.

#textDataProblems
#didNotSeeThatComing

Thank you StackOverflow!